# Magento 2 coupon apply and remove event

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, coupon

I want to redirect to /checkout if a coupon is applied and it is valid. I have tried this event **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost** this only works on coupon cancel and /cart page. Not working on apply function and also in /checkout/#payment page where it uses ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

There are no events in magento 2. so you need to create plugin for this.

following code you need to use :

add di.xml in following path

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement">
        <plugin name="checkout_coupon_apply"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CheckoutCouponApply"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

now Add CheckoutCouponApply.php file in following path :

Vendor\Extension\Plugin\

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CheckoutCouponApply {

    public function beforeSet(CouponManagement $subject, $cartId, $couponCode)
    {
         // Do what you need to do
    }
}
```